# gitlab CI/CD xxx.tmp/TRIGGER_PAYLOAD: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, bash, gitlab-ci-runner

On my window computer, I use git bash to register and start gitlab runner. gitlab-runner.exe stored in C:Runner directory. I open git-bash terminal, cd /c/Runner to register and run gitlab runner as following：
[image]

If I use CI/CD>>Schedules UI to start pipelines, everything works fine. But when I use trigger command like following, pipeline job failed.

```
curl -X POST \
     -F token=xxxxxxx \
     -F ref=develop \
     http://git.xxxxxxxxx/trigger/pipeline
```

Error message is:
[image]

It seems that “/c/Runner/C:/Runner/builds...” is a wrong path. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you very much.

BTW: For some reason, I have to use bash terminal on window to start gitlab-runner.

Comment: If I set a File Variable, use CI/CD>>Schedules UI to start pipelines will also fail.  The real problem is that the path to the temporary file is illegal.

Comment: add following code to config.toml file can fix this issue.
builds_dir="/c/Runner/builds/"   
cache_dir="/c/Runner/cache/"